# # for window.location.pathname

Tags: javascript, window.location

I'm trying to redirect to a relative url, like this

```
setTimeout(window.location.pathname = '/help/fusion/index.php#3', 500);
```

But the # seems to cause a problem when being passed to the window.location.pathname. The error is

> 'The requested URL /help/fusion/index.php#3 was not found on this server.'

but the url that the browser actually displays is localhost/help/fusion/index.php%233#1. Anybody know how to avoid this?

Comment: `#3` is the **fragment identifier** and is normally the value that you get when accessing `location.hash`. I.e. it is a different part of the URL, it is not part of the path. Because of that it is encoded automatically when you are trying to set it as part of the path (`#` becomes `%23`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `window.location` to redirect in javascript and pass a function to he `setTimeOut` function. Try this:

```
setTimeout(function() { window.location = '/help/fusion/index.php#3'; }, 500);
```

Comment: fantastic, thanks. I was under the impression that I could only use the url formatted in such a way with location.pathname